# Unable to read HttpResponse from HTTPS

Tags: c#, https

```
public void HttpsRequest(string address)
    {
        string data;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        request.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        byte[] resp = new byte[(int)response.ContentLength];
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

I get an *Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow* when I am trying to read a page over https. Errors occur because the response gives me ContentLenght = -1.
Using fiddler I can see that the page was received. Some other websites using HTTPS works fine but most of them not.

Comment: Could you provide an address that would duplicate the issue?

Comment: Why did you initialize unused variable `resp`?

Comment: Which line does the exception occur?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: The line that throws the error is not used. Simply delete it to get your code works with all urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I query https://www.google.com, I get the same error message, because not every response has a content length. Use this code to avoid the problem:

```
public static void HttpsRequest(string address)
{
  string data;
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
   request.Method = "GET";

   using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected: not every response contains content length.

There is nothing in your sample that requires length to be known, so simply not reading it maybe enough.

Answer (score 0):

From [HttpWebResponse.ContentLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength.aspx)

`The ContentLength property contains the value of the Content-Length header returned with the response. If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, ContentLength is set to the value -1.`

If `Content-Length` header is not set it does not mean that you got a bad response.